# Using beanstalkd vs ActiveMQ for queuing on PHP Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, activemq-classic, message-queue, beanstalkd

I have a PHP system where users interact with others; when user do some action, then this action will forward to all users following this user as member feed.

I currently use **beanstalkd** queue system, so I send massage to beanstalkd and beanstalkd complete this action and send it to all users and do database handling like insert.

But I have a lot of problems in beanstalkd, and recently I read about **Active MQ**.

So can I use and replace beanstalkd with Active MQ and use Active MQ as queuing system to complete this action in order not waiting to complete response and reduce page response?

Or if there is any other related system please help me?

Comment: What problems are you having exactly, with Beanstalk? I don't think people will be able to recommend one over the other without knowing a good number of details about your system. Also, if you are having problems, it is usually much easier to fix them rather than to swap a component out - you might get worse problems with Active MQ, and then you'd have to swap again!

Comment: I am using Zend framework and Doctrine, i am having a memory leak with the beanstalk and doctrine because it is dealing with lot of records and memory

Comment: **Would you edit this question containing the code that might be responsible?** As it stands, this question isn't answerable, since there's no detail to respond to, and if you have a problem with large numbers of records, moving to another system might just replicate the problem there.